# According to Catholicism, did God create humans to directly perform His Will in the physical world?

Tags: catholicism, creation, nature-of-man, love, will-of-god

I am wondering if the following ideas/questions would be considered compatible with orthodox Catholic theology:

1. If God is Love, if humans are made in His image, and if humans are made by Love and For Love, could one say that the purpose of human life is to enact the Will of Love in the material world?

The above might sound like an obvious point; the distinction here is maybe better stated by this question:

2. Did God choose to create rational beings so that, in the material world He created, there would be something that enacted and performed His Will in a physical way?

Comment: This would be comparable to the idea that Angels enact the Will of God in the spiritual plane of existence. Humans exist so that the material world is not devoid of an agent who would perform God's will

Comment: This doesn't make sense: "to enact the Will of Love material world?" Please reword.

Comment: What does Matthew 22:36-40 tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the *only* "purpose of life", but it's one of the things that we get to do.

"15 The Lord God took the man and placed him in the orchard in Eden to care for it and to maintain it." -- Genesis 2:15 (NET) from: https://lumina.bible.org/bible/Genesis+2

Jesus gives us additional purposes of life in the Gospels:

- “37 Jesus said to him, “‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart, with all your soul, and with all your mind.’ 38 This is the first and greatest commandment. 39 The second is like it: ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’ 40 All the law and the prophets depend on these two commandments.” -- Matthew 22:37-40 (NET) from: lumina.bible.org/bible/Matthew+22
- 8 Jesus answered him, “It is written, ‘You are to worship the Lord your God and serve only him.’” Luke 4:8 (NET) from https://lumina.bible.org/bible/Luke+3 (as Jesus was speaking about this reference from Deut. 6:13: “You must revere the Lord your God, serve him, and take oaths using only his name.”)
- “He said to them, “Go into all the world and preach the gospel to every creature.” Mark 16:15 (NET) from: lumina.bible.org/bible/Mark+16 It's also the foundational quote used by: www.wayofthemaster.com

The point is that there isn't only "one purpose of life", but many purposes! We aren't single-faceted people. We are multi-faceted people! All we have to do is look towards God & ask Him, what His purposes are for our lives. Pray about it. Ask Him what His purposes are for your life & see what He says! :)

Comment: Thank you. I think some people may have misunderstood my question a little: I never believed that there was only one purpose for human life, or for creation. God is of such immense intelligence, I would think that almost everything serves multiple purposes at once.

Answer (score 0):

**Did God Make Humans To Directly Perform His Will In The Physical Universe?**

Since God created the physical universe, it would seem unlikely that he has need of our efforts to accomplish things in that universe.

> Ecclesiastes 12:13  Let us hear the conclusion of the whole matter:
>   Fear God, and keep his commandments: for this is the whole duty of
>   man.

It would seem that God is more interested in our motives, beliefs, and choices than the physical tasks we accomplish.

Comment: Could you demonstrate that this is the Catholic perspective on the question?

Answer (score -1):

God created man out of love. We are his children but he also gave us free will. He created everyone and everything. He would not have needed to create people to do his will. It is his hope that we do his will but remember Satan has rule over the earth that is why we need to follow God. Satan tempts us daily in almost everything we do. God has a plan for our lives and I don't believe that can be changed but our everyday choices are what we do good when we have God/ Jesus in our lives, and bad when we let our guard down or refuse to believe and then Satan sneaks in.

Comment: This answer does not seem to be addressing the Question "According to Catholicism".

Comment: What does that mean "According to Catholicism? I was raised Catholic and am now just Christian no religion but my answer would be the same.

Comment: It means you did not read the question.  The person asking is looking for an answer from the Two thousand year Catholic Christian perspective, not that of “Just a Christian”.  They want an answer from the the original Christians.

Comment: Being in the Catholic church  most of my life. Going through  catechism and Catholic  school  my answer would still be the same.